# Why doesn't changing the Model also change the view in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, sorting, ember.js

[image]

I have 4 posts. Each one has a title and an Author. Right now, it is sorted by Author. I would like to click a button (such as Sort By Title) and have the information be sorted by title instead of by author.

So far, I know that I am sorting the authors and titles and the model is being updated. The problem is displaying the updated information in the view. For some reason, I assumed that if I just did `this.set('model', newModel)` that the new information would display automatically. This is not so.

Here is my code.

**practice.hbs**

```
{{outlet}}


<button {{action "sortTitles"}}>Sort by Title</button>
<button {{action "sortAuthors"}}>Sort by Author</button>
{{#each model as |post|}}
    <h2>Title: {{post.title}}</h2>
    <h3>Author: {{post.author}}</h3>
{{/each}}
```

**routes/practice.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
        var myArray = [{
            title: "Learning EmberJS",
            author: "Erik Hatchett"
        },{
            title: "Controllers are Dead",
            author: "Frank Treacy"
        },{
            title: "Diddly Doo",
            author: "No I'm Adrian"
        },{
            title: "Yisss",
            author: "Dank Sir"
        }];

        myArray.sort(function(a,b) {
            if (a.author > b.author) {
                console.log(a + " is greater than " + b);
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                console.log(b + " is greater than " + a);
                return -1;
            }
        });

        if ("dat" < "cat") {
            console.log("ayy");
        }

        console.log(myArray[2]);
        return myArray;
    }
});
```

**controllers/practice.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var sortByAuthor = function(a,b) {
            if (a.author > b.author) {
                console.log(a + " is greater than " + b);
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                console.log(b + " is greater than " + a);
                return -1;
            }
        };

var sortByTitle = function(a,b) {
            if (a.title > b.title) {
                console.log(a + " is greater than " + b);
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                console.log(b + " is greater than " + a);
                return -1;
            }
        };



export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    actions: {
        sortAuthors() {
            var myModel = this.get('model');
            console.log(myModel[0].author);
            myModel.sort(sortByAuthor);
            console.log(myModel[0].author);
            this.set('model', myModel);
        },
        sortTitles() {
            var myModel = this.get('model');
            myModel.sort(sortByTitle);
            console.log(myModel[0].title);
            this.set('model', myModel);
        }
    }
});
```

The information is definitely being sorted and the model is definitely being updated. It just doesn't appear to display the sorted information.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, which now contains a code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set your model to another value inside your controller. This will not work as this is not how the model binding is setup between the route and the controller. The model must be managed by the route.

Instead, create a controller property called sortedRows which you will update from your controller action. Update your template to loop through sortedRows.

*bonus answer*

Another, more idiomatic solution is you can set a sort key from your controller action, and have sortedRows be a computed property that fires when sortKey changes, and returns the sorted model.

Some variation of the following should work (I have not tested this):

template.hbs

```
<button {{action (action 'sortBy' 'title')}}>Sort by Title</button>
<button {{action (action 'sortBy' 'author')}}>Sort by Author</button>

{{#each sortedRows as |row|}}
  <h2>Title: {{row.title}}</h2>
  <h3>Author: {{row.author}}</h3>
{{/each}}
```

controller.js

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  sortKey: 'author', // or whatever you want the default sort to be
  sortedRows: Ember.computed('sortKey', function() {
    return this.get('model').sortBy(this.get('sortKey'));
  },

  actions: {
    sortBy(sortKey) {
      this.set('sortKey', sortKey);
    }
  }
});
```

route.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return [...];
  }
});
```

*bonus bonus*

You can simplify this further by using Ember.computed.sort, which I will leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I wouldn't have thought of this myself. Thank you. I will try the Ember.computed.sort as well.

Comment: don't forget to add more dependent keys to the sortedRows computed property if your model data might change, so that ember knows when to fire the function

Comment: Question: why did you do `{{action (action 'sortBy' 'title')}}` and not just `{{action 'sort'By' 'title'}}`? It doesn't appear to make a difference if I remove it.

Comment: it's a closure action. the reason i used a closure action in this situation is that it allowed me to 'curry' the function call with an argument, in this case 'title'. if i had used the other format i wouldn't be able to pass an argument to the function through the template

Comment: Another question, when you called `this.get('sortedRows`). Are you computing the sorted version of the rows every time, or are the sorted rows computed once in the back-end and then served again and again?

Comment: I don't see that line in the code I wrote. But to add a bit about computed properties--they are evaluated lazily and cached. If the model data changes the computed property will be recomputed but only if its value is consumed somewhere. In this case the value is consumed in the template.

Comment: You could simply use `Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortKey')`. If you use plain computed, you should add model als dependency. Otherwise `sortedRows` will not be updated if `model` changes.

Comment: Yes I mentioned that

Comment: Thanks a ton. I got it working using the `computed.sort` method (which was actually better because later on I needed to sort by ascending/descending). Really gave me a good kick start though. I appreciate it.